# How do I close one specific csv file that is open in the excel application on windows using python, given the path to that file?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, windows-10, subprocess

I have a script that writes data to a csv file, but if that csv file is open (in the excel application on Windows 10) then it generates a PermissionError.  This makes sense.

I want to be able to catch the PermissionError and then close the file down, specifically close that one csv file that is open in the excel application on Windows 10.  I do NOT want to close down the entire excel application, but rather identify the specific file and then close that, leaving any other files open in excel untouched.

I have looked into using subprocess to do this, but it is not clear to me how I would achieve that.  It seems like the most likely route, unless there is a better route anyone can suggest.

The ultimate code would look something like this:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

path_to_file = 'path/to/file.csv'

df = pd.DataFrame()

try:
    
    df.to_csv(path_to_file) # file that is currently open
    
except PermissionError:
    
    print('Shutting the Open File')
    time.sleep(5)
    shut_the_open_file(path_to_file) # need to figure out this code for closing the currently open file
    df.to_csv(path_to_file)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially interface with **Excel** using a python module called [`xlwings`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html)

Use the API to iterate over all your open workbooks and close the ones you want by name.

```
pip install xlwings

import xlwings as xl

for app in xl.apps:
    for book in app.books:
        if book.fullname == r"your_file_path":
            book.close()
```